# How to pass arguments to function in a random number generator without generating a new random number?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is a program for matching input with random number generated by a function.

There are three functions

- 'rangen()' for generating the random number
- 'index()' to display the webpage, there we can input a value to check with the random number generated by rangen()
- 'checker()' for checking the values

I need to pass the value generated by 'rangen()' to 'checker()'.

I cannot call rangen() in my checker() function because the random number will change in the same session. I need the random number to be the same until we get the result: 'Congratulation!!! Number Matched'

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import random

# Create your views here.


def rangen(request):
    rannumber= random.randint(1,3)
    print(rannumber)
    return rannumber


def index(request):

    return render(request,'generator/index.html')

def checker(request):

    print(rannumber)
    if request.method=='POST':
        innum = int(request.POST['inputnumber'])
        print(innum)
        if (rannumber==innum):
            flag = 'Congratulation!!! Number Matched'
            return render(request,'generator/index.html',{'flag':flag})
        elif(innum>rannumber):
            flag = 'Oops!!! You Entered a High Value, Try Again!!!'
            return render(request,'generator/index.html',{'flag':flag})
        else:
            flag = 'Oops!!! You Entered a Low Value, Try Again!!!'
            return render(request,'generator/index.html',{'flag':flag})
```

index.html

```
<div class="formclass">
      <h1>Random Generator</h1>
      <form action="checker" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Enter you guess</h3>
        <input type="text" name="inputnumber" placeholder="Enter Your Guess" required><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
        <h1>{{flag}}</h1>
      </form>
    </div>
```

No errors when I run the server, but when I provide my guess value it shows

> 'NAME ERROR: name 'rannumber' is not defined'

Comment: That is logical, you need to generate one first, as in `rannumber = rangen(request)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: in checker() function?

 It is not possible, because, if we do that, random number will change even if we type a not matching number.
please think about that too... that is the issue here

Comment: no not in the `checker` function, you need something persistent...

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: Yeah... It works... Thank you sir